# While doing ASP.NET MVC 3, I wonder why developers want MORE javascript libraries like backbone and coffeescript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

As both an .NET developer and have done javascript for over 15 years.  I cannot understand why people want to add more javascript libraries into their project.

I started in the 90's with the javascript alerts and all the syntax.  Then in 2001 I wrote XML Data Islands which was invented by Microsoft but only worked on IE for windows, not even IE for the Mac.  Essentially is was AJAX before AJAX was coined around 2005.  XML Data Islands was Javascript/XML hitting a server.

In 1999, Microsoft created the XMLHTTP ActiveX control in Internet Explorer 5, which was later adopted by Mozilla, Safari, Opera and other browsers as the XMLHttpRequest JavaScript object.

Then I used EXT / Prototype / JQuery ... and the clear winner is Jquery.  I end up seeing so many bloated not Dried out javascript all the time and yet people tout Coffeescript and Backbone and Knockout as solutions.  Even Google has Dart.

I even see articles that say "Backbone will pretty much replace your MVC views and controller logic."  I am stuck with yuck.... Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks and libraries are about reducing the amount of code needed to accomplish frequent tasks.  If a framework can do that for me, I want to learn and use it.  If not, I'll pass.

Comment: Short and sweet.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Single Page Architecture!

Javascript has evolved from just showing you an alert and posting your form to actually running your website. All these frameworks are a natural evolution to helping you develop a very snazzy page that users want to use. Without these frameworks it would be very hard to build a real cool website, you would just be stuck in last decade.

But pick and choose your framework wisely so you don't have to ask the 'why' again. :)

Comment: I hear you.  I'm tired of asking 'why'   Thanks.

Comment: Single Page Architecture - No different than ASP.NET WebForm super control to rule them all. There are valid times to use this style of architecture but it should be done only when having a good reason. The things people are doing with JavaScript are causing us to rethink things but at the same time doesn’t mean all the trends are right. One should be very causes on following all the trends as they can leave you with code that's hard to scale or manage. It's best to look for a good balance between server-side and client-side, as each language as with each technology has its pros and cons.